# Excel VBA - Execute string as code

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to execute the following string as code using Evaluate but get Error 2029. Anyone know why?

Help much appreciated.

```
Calculation = "Format(""21/08/2012"", ""MMM"")"
Value = Evaluate(Calculation)
```

Comment: Evaluate is used for worksheet functions/udfs, not code per se

Comment: @Kyle Hmm. Thank you for that. I was using the code above as a quick example. I don't suppose there's an equivalent to 'Evaluate' that can be used for VBA code?

Comment: @Kyle I'm creating a class that connects to a database using ADO. It holds the data in an array. I'd like to create a method where I can just feed 2 arguments and it will add a column and apply the code to it (The two arguments are the new column name and the code to apply). So, in the class I add and name the new column and use a 'For Loop', but I need some way to feed in the code to apply. I can easily construct the necessary code by breaking apart the "Code String" and reconstructing it as needed to work with the array. But I need it to then run as actual code. And there's my problem.

Comment: You can't do that, why not write the data modification code as a method of the class if you'll use it often, if not, why not run the code on the array and pass back the altered object. Or even better add your additional column in sql

Comment: @Kyle I can't predict what the code will be as the requirements will vary so much, so I can't write it into the class. I don't want to pass the array object back and forth as the whole point is to automate the boring bits (the redim, finding the ubound, the loop, etc). Which leaves open the last suggestion, write it into the SQL, which sounds like the best option. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead

```
Calculation = "TEXT(""21/08/2012"", ""MMM"")"
```

EVALUATE converts formulas to results, and FORMAT is a VBA function. The formula equivalent is TEXT.

You can also skip the evaluate and use the FORMAT function on the date directly.

Answer (score -1):

You can use most worksheet functions in VBA directly with `Application.WorksheetFunction.` - for example - try this out:

```
Sub DateExample()

Dim StringTest As String
StringTest = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text("12/08/2012", "MMM")

Cells(1, 1).Value = StringTest

End Sub
```

Good Luck